# Solving $\dfrac{x}{1-e^{-x}} = 3.034$

Tags: solution-verification, exponential-function, problem-solving, factoring

I am stuck in this question in finding the value of $x$ :-

$$\frac{x}{1-e^{-x}} = 3.034$$

I have tried this question using log on both sides.

Like this:-

$$\log x - \log (1-e^{-x}) = \log (3.034)$$

$$\frac{1}{x\:} - \frac{1}{1-e^{-x}} =\log(3.034)$$

Given answer:- $x= 2.86$

But it turned out bad after taking l.c.m

I don't know how to solve after this..

Please help me & correct me if I have done something wrong calculations.

Comment: I don't think this can be solved analytically; you'd need a numerical method like Newton's root-finding method for $f(x)=e^{-x} + \frac{1}{3.034} x - 1$.

Comment: $\log a - \log b \neq \frac1a-\frac1b$

Comment: Terrible title.  Please re-write it so it applies to YOUR SPECIFIC problem.

Comment: There is no elementary solution for this equation, however you could express the solution in terms of the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). Using this you can solve the general class of equations
$$x=a+be^{cx},$$
for any complex $a,b,c$.

Answer (score 2):

The analytic solution to:

$$\frac{x}{1 - e^{-x}} = a$$

is

$$x = W\left(-a e^{-a}\right)+a$$

where $W$ is the product log function or [Lambert's $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Evaluated with $a = 3.034$ gives $$x = 2.8603.$$

Answer (score 2):

As @David G. Stork answered, the only explicit solution involves Lambert function.

Assuming that you cannot use it, you can have quite good *approximations* for the non trivial zero of function
$$f(x)=x-a(1-e^{-x})\qquad \text{with} \qquad a >0$$ for which
$$f'(x)=1-a e^{-x} \qquad \text{and} \qquad f''(x)=a e^{-x} \quad >0 \quad \forall x$$

This firstderivative cancel at
$$x_*=\log(a)  \implies f(x_*)= -a+\log (a)+1 \le 0$$ So, around $x=x_*$, make a simple series expansion
$$f(x)=f(x_*)+\frac 12 f''(x_*)(x-x_*)^2+ O\left( (x-x_*)^3\right)$$ which gives
$$x \sim x_*+\sqrt{-2 \frac{f(x_*)}{f''(x_*)}}$$ that is to say
$$x_0=\log(a)+ \sqrt{2(a-\log (a)-1)}$$ If $a=3.034$, this gives $x_0=2.46938$.

Now, perform a single iteration of Newton method; it would give $x_1=2.88357$ which is not too bad.

Comment: Gosh... why *this* got an upvote but my solution not... hard to fathom.

Answer (score 0):

That's a form of transcendental equation.  So it has no elementary solution, you can only approximate it.

In general, if you see $x$ both inside and outside a trig function, log, or exponential, the equation is transcendental and you have to use numerical techniques to get close to an answer.

The simplest practical way is to rewrite it as two functions of $x$ that are equal, and graph them both, then find the point of intersection.

Comment: Transcendental equations can have analytic solutions.

Comment: ... precisely as I showed.

Comment: I think you mean _elementary_, not _analytic_.